# How to copy a surface of an object

Tags: snapping

just simple and quick question, is there a way to make a plane object like text to copy surface of another object, like in the picture?
[image]

Comment: Yes, use the shrinkwrap modifier

Comment: Thank you, I have to go through the modifiers, there is a plenty things what they can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One mesh can be projected onto the surface of another, by adding a [Shrinkwrap](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/shrinkwrap.html?highlight=shrinkwrap) modifier to it.

> The Shrinkwrap modifier allows an object to “shrink” to the surface of
>   another object. It moves each vertex of the object being modified to
>   the closest position on the surface of the given mesh (using one of
>   the four methods available).
>
> It can be applied to meshes, lattices, curves, surfaces and texts.

For your example, the shrinkwrap modifier should probably be set to **project**, with the **X** and **negative** options checked.

[image: Shrinkwrap modifier]